# turning my dynamic IP into a static one using a VPS?

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, proxy, ssh-tunnel, mamp

I'm doing development with MAMP on OSX and need to get around a problem I'm having due to my dynamic IP.

I'm using a payment API which has an IP whitelist even for development calls and I keep having to get the client to update their whitelist every time it changes.

My ISP won't give me a static IP.

I have a VPS running CENTOS that I can use as a proxy - I know that I can set firefox up to give a remote server the impression that my browser has the VPS's static IP.

My question is, can I use an ssh tunnel to make it appear that my local OSX machine's MAMP server IP is actually that my VPS's IP?

In this way I add my VPS's static IP to the whitelist and stop troubling my client!

I'm very open to any other solutions to the problem too!

Answer (score 1):

SSH tunnel or VPN tunnel, either will suffice. Once you have the tunnel in place, and it seems stable, then start forwarding your port from the static IP to the internal VPN/SSH Tunnel IP.

I used this method before to get around the fact that my ISP blocks port 80.